# Need to restart rinet manually on reboot

Tags: networking, upstart, systemd, port-forwarding

I redirect an internet connection through my desktop from WiFi to Ethernet for use by a Raspberry Pi. I then use `rinet` ([manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man8/rinetd.8.html)) to redirect one port back through the desktop so that I can access a web page hosted on the Pi from the local network. However, my issue is that, on rebooting the desktop, I have to manually restart `rinetd` using `/etc/init.d/rinetd`. I have tried adding a command to the startup applications, to no avail. It would seem that the timing for startup applications is wrong. So:

1. Does anyone know of a concise explanation of the 'Startup applications' timing in Ubuntu
2. I had thought about writing an upstart script, but considering Ubuntu is moving to systemd, perhaps I should just do that. Any advice on that front?